# Propel 1.7 order by natsort

Tags: php, sorting, propel

Is there a way using `Propel 1.7` to use a natural sorting algorithm in a `orderByXXX` function, so I get:

```
"thing1", "thing2", "thing10"
```

instead of:

```
"thing1", "thing10", "thing2"
```

I know I can convert to an array and and do it in there, or I could maybe even figure something out using a raw sql query, but I'd prefer to do it against the propel collection itself.

Answer (score 0):

The actual ordering has nothing to do with propel. See http://www.copterlabs.com/blog/natural-sorting-in-mysql/ to find a solution.

It could then look like

```
$query
    ->addAscendingOrderByColumn('LENGTH(title)');
    ->addAscendingOrderByColumn('title');
```